# Latest WebRTC Client for Android

Tags: android, webrtc

http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/

Link above to build webrtc client for Android is outdated. Does anyone have instructions for compiling latest WebRTC code to build libjingle_peerconnection.jar for Android?

Answer (score 0):

The Webrtc guys changed the checkout method for the code.

The change was done very recently so i guess most places with instructions will be outdated (at least as of today)
you can see the changes [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/U01RHX9NIDA).

IMHO, your best bet is to follow instructions on [Webrtc getting started page](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started)

and if you are having trouble ask here or on the [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc) group

best of luck...